# Issue With Google map polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map and I need to draw links between different locations on the map. I am using google maps polyline to draw links between different points. Following is the code:

```
// code to draw map
var map;
var mapProp = {
        // center : new google.maps.LatLng(51.4848, -0.20325),
        zoom : 8,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

 // data to show the links between locations, first part of lat & long denotes from location and second part is to location for a link.
 var links_data = [
 {"path":[{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-2.985655},{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655},{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-3.038971}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405},{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244},{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405},{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685}]}, 
 {"path":[{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-2.989244},{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866},{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866},{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-3.014986}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866},{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-3.014405},{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-3.022483}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-3.038971},{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655},{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483},{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-3.038971}]},
 {"path":[{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483},{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655}]}
 ];

    // draw links
    for(var i = 0 ; i < links_data.length; i++)
    {
      var latLng = links_data[i].path; 
      // polylines lat long array
      var polypoints = [];
      for ( var j = 0; j < latLng .length; j++) {
        polypoints[j] = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(latLng [j].lat),
                parseFloat(latLng [j].lng));
    }

    var link = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path : polypoints,
       geodesic : true,
       strokeColor : col,
       strokeOpacity : 0.5,
       strokeWeight : 3,
       title : "test"
    });
    link.setMap(map);
}
```

I am facing a issue the maps sometimes shows irrelevant lines (few of them marked in black ellipse) as shown in the image below:

[image]

any idea whats the issue about?. I am using goggle api from the following url
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp;

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in the question itself.

Comment: Edited the complete code except the one to draw the markers (wifi icons)

Comment: if I understand you want to draw 18 lines. Each "path" contains the coordinates of start and end of a line. right?

Comment: [I don't see the problem that you show in your picture with the code as posted (although did have to define `col` and set a center for the map)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vk007b6j/)

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes you are right .

Comment: @geocodezip as I said earlier the problem occurs only sometimes not always. I did click on the link you provided, I can still see the problem

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I did use Chrome.I can see 3 tangling lines from your fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

You don't populate the path coordinates in the right way, the full red color lines are lines repeted more and more time and the 50% opacity lines are lines draw  one time only, this mean  same coordinate are repeted. Probably  you are loading  the coordinates in path in wrong way or in wrong sequence. Or You are trying to draw more lines but for mistake you draw one or few lines wrong. The code you are provide is not enough for a correct evaluation. probably is necessary evalute the coordinates of marker too.

I have played with your code and this is a functioning and self-consistent code page
I have found some minor mistake in coding eand some declaration i preferred move in top of the script. Essentially the problem are the coordinates of the points in many case the coordinates refer to the same line in reverse order or start for the same point and are very near each other. Probabily you need to clear the double lines (i have signed some) and define better whiat you want show in the map. 
I hope this is useful for you

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>test sandbox 8</title>

      <style type="text/css">
        #main {
          margin: 60px 15px; 
        }
        #map { 
          min-height: 600px; 
          min-width: 800px; 
        }
      </style>

          <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script>
        // code to draw map
        var map;
        var col = '#FF0000';
        var link ;
        var latLng;
        var polypoints;

        function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
                center : new google.maps.LatLng(53.40, -2.99),
                zoom : 12,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

         // data to show the links between locations, first part of lat & long denotes from location and second part is to location for a link.
         var links_data = [
         {"path":[{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-2.985655},{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655}]},
         {"path":[{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655},{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-3.038971}]},
         {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405}]},
         {"path":[{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405},{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685}]},
         {"path":[{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244},{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405}]},
         {"path":[{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405},{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244}]},
         {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244}]},
         {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685}]}, 
         {"path":[{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-2.989244},{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866}]},   // line 9   same origin of line  13
         {"path":[{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866},{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685}]},   // line 10  same origin of line 13
         {"path":[{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866},{"lat":53.407086,"lng":-2.989244}]},   // line 11
         {"path":[{"lat":53.409477,"lng":-2.982685},{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-3.014986}]},   // line 12
         {"path":[{"lat":53.388615,"lng":-3.015866},{"lat":53.390648,"lng":-3.014405}]},   // line 13 
         {"path":[{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-3.014405},{"lat":53.389557,"lng":-3.022483}]},   // line 14 
         {"path":[{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-3.038971},{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483}]},   // line 15 repeat line 17 in reverse order 
         {"path":[{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655},{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483}]},   // line 16  repeat line 18 in reverse order
         {"path":[{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483},{"lat":53.408123,"lng":-3.038971}]},   // line 17
         {"path":[{"lat":53.410152,"lng":-3.022483},{"lat":53.416366,"lng":-2.985655}]}    // line 18
         ];

            // draw links
            for(var i = 0 ; i < links_data.length; i++)
            {
              latLng = links_data[i].path; 
              // polylines lat long array
              polypoints = [];
              for ( var j = 0; j < latLng.length; j++) {
                polypoints[j] = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(latLng[j].lat),
                        parseFloat(latLng[j].lng));

              }
             link = new google.maps.Polyline({
               path : polypoints,
               geodesic : true,
               strokeColor : col,
               strokeOpacity : 0.5,
               strokeWeight : 3,
               title : "test"
            });
            link.setMap(map);
           }
        }

         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
           <div id="map"></div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Edited the complete code except the one to draw the markers (wifi icons)

Comment: Yes you are right there are double lines and thats the part of the requirement. For example, I need a link from A to B and also B to A

Comment: these double lines make that the line becomes more colorful because the opacity of the two lines is the sum. Well the code i posted is useful for you?

Comment: in the answer you said, you did clear few double lines.. How did you do that? by changing the lat lng? if that the case , it will not be helpful

Comment: I don't clear nothing. I haven't change your coordinates. The sample i provided is base on your coordinates only. If you look at your code there some change in declaration and in mistaken `space` in code.