# How to fix Google Maps Polyline straight lines congestion?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I am using google maps polyline to draw path over map. Everything is fine but it seems like at some places it shows multiple straight lines. Check image attached.

[I am not able to attach image due to less reputation. please click to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP1QO.png)

You can see in image that markers are placed accurately but don't know what happens to polylines.

I have referred to these solutions but never got any help.

1. [Unexplained extra Polyline drawn - Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953952/unexplained-extra-polyline-drawn-google-maps-api-v3)
2. [Issue With Google map polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435675/issue-with-google-map-polyline)
3. [Remove straight line in google map path using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836341/remove-straight-line-in-google-map-path-using-javascript)

Below is the code:

```
    //Initializing map
    var locations = [
        ["Start point at Bopal Lake City Travels (Pick up By Auto/Van) (04:30 PM) [23.0161,72.5928]", "23.0161", "72.5928"],
        ["End point at Station road polo victory\t (09:20 AM) [26.9214,75.7974]", "26.9214", "75.7974"],
        ["Point at ISKCON Cross Road, Iskcon BRTS Bus Stop.(Pick Up By Auto/Van) (16:45:00 PM) [23.0273,72.5085]", "23.0273", "72.5085", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at Patel Travels, Ratnamani Complex, Satellite Road (Pick Up By Auto) (16:55:00 PM) [23.0263,72.5252]", "23.0263", "72.5252", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at Jhansi ki Rani BRTS Corridor, Opp. Nehru Nagar Bus Stand, Ahmedabad (17:10:00 PM) [23.0231,72.5363]", "23.0231", "72.5363", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at IntrCity SmartBus Lounge Paldi (17:30:00 PM) [23.0153,72.5632]", "23.0153", "72.5632", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at ST Shri Jain Travels (Pick Up By Auto/Van) (17:40:00 PM) [23.0201,72.5938]", "23.0201", "72.5938", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at Sahibaugh namaste circle (18:30:00 PM) [23.0431,72.5894]", "23.0431", "72.5894", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at Memco Ranawat Travels (18:15:00 PM) [23.0549,72.631]", "23.0549", "72.631", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at Gurukripa Travels, Nr. Naroda Patiya Circle, Opp. S.T Workshop, Naroda, Ahmedabad (18:25:00 PM) [23.0655,72.6427]", "23.0655", "72.6427", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at  Naroda Bethak Gulsan Travels (18:30:00 PM) [23.0722,72.6485]", "23.0722", "72.6485", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"],
        ["Point at Nana Chiloda Keshav Tours & Travels (18:40:00 PM) [23.1121,72.6736]", "23.1121", "72.6736", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"]....
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: 1,
        panControl: !1,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        scaleControl: !0,
        scaleControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT},
        zoomControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT},
        streetViewControl: !1
      });

      // Placing markers
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          icon: locations[i][3],
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.close(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      }

      //Polyline Code
      var flightPlanCoordinates = [{"lat":23.68178368,"lng":73.3649292},{"lat":23.68178368,"lng":73.3649292},{"lat":23.68211174,"lng":73.36606598},{"lat":23.68241882,"lng":73.36714172},{"lat":23.68241882,"lng":73.36714172},{"lat":23.6826725,"lng":73.3680954},{"lat":23.68301582,"lng":73.3693161},{"lat":23.68344498,"lng":73.37083435},{"lat":23.68344498,"lng":73.37084198},{"lat":23.68371582,"lng":73.37143707},{"lat":23.68387413,"lng":73.37171936},{"lat":23.68423271,"lng":73.37225342},{"lat":23.68522453,"lng":73.37348175},{"lat":23.68522644,"lng":73.37348175},{"lat":23.68622971,"lng":73.37474823},{"lat":23.68709373,"lng":73.37572479},{"lat":23.68709373,"lng":73.37572479},{"lat":23.68791771,"lng":73.37660217},{"lat":23.68807602,"lng":73.37683868},{"lat":23.68820953,"lng":73.37711334},{"lat":23.68831253,"lng":73.37739563},{"lat":23.68842506,"lng":73.37791443},{"lat":23.68843269,"lng":73.37811279},{"lat":23.68850136,"lng":73.37839508},{"lat":23.68850136,"lng":73.37839508},{"lat":23.68861198,"lng":73.37859344},{"lat":23.68872833,"lng":73.37875366},{"lat":23.68881416,"lng":73.37884521},{"lat":23.68890381,"lng":73.37895966},{"lat":23.68899155,"lng":73.37911987},{"lat":23.68909454,"lng":73.3792572},{"lat":23.68909454,"lng":73.3792572},{"lat":23.68931389,"lng":73.37970734},{"lat":23.68934441,"lng":73.37981415},{"lat":23.68941689,"lng":73.37993622},{"lat":23.68944359,"lng":73.38013458},{"lat":23.68945312,"lng":73.38030243},{"lat":23.68942451,"lng":73.38047028},{"lat":23.68944359,"lng":73.38063049},{"lat":23.68944359,"lng":73.38063049},{"lat":23.68943024,"lng":73.38078308},{"lat":23.68939018,"lng":73.38092804},{"lat":23.6893692,"lng":73.38106537},{"lat":23.68934059,"lng":73.3812027},{"lat":23.68927956,"lng":73.38140869},{"lat":23.68927956,"lng":73.38140869},{"lat":23.68897247,"lng":73.38247681},{"lat":23.68897247,"lng":73.38247681},{"lat":23.68868637,"lng":73.3835144},{"lat":23.68855095,"lng":73.38401794},{"lat":23.68836403,"lng":73.38489532},{"lat":23.68838882,"lng":73.38507843},{"lat":23.68842888,"lng":73.38526917},{"lat":23.68842888,"lng":73.38526917},{"lat":23.6884861,"lng":73.38544464},{"lat":23.68863869,"lng":73.38578033},{"lat":23.68874741,"lng":73.38592529},{"lat":23.68885994,"lng":73.38603973},{"lat":23.6891098,"lng":73.38620758},{"lat":23.68925858,"lng":73.3862381},{"lat":23.68941689,"lng":73.38626099},{"lat":23.68941689,"lng":73.38626099},{"lat":23.69036102,"lng":73.38641357},{"lat":23.690588,"lng":73.38643646},{"lat":23.6905899,"lng":73.38643646},{"lat":23.74006844,"lng":73.42392731},{"lat":23.74006844,"lng":73.42392731},{"lat":23.73686981,"lng":73.41983032},{"lat":23.73789406,"lng":73.42114258},{"lat":23.73898125,"lng":73.42253876},{"lat":23.74006844,"lng":73.42392731},{"lat":23.74072266,"lng":73.42477417},{"lat":23.74072266,"lng":73.42477417},{"lat":23.68344498,"lng":73.37083435},{"lat":23.68371582,"lng":73.37143707},{"lat":23.68387413,"lng":73.37171936},{"lat":23.68423271,"lng":73.37225342},{"lat":23.68522453,"lng":73.37348175},{"lat":23.68622971,"lng":73.37474823},{"lat":23.68709373,"lng":73.37572479},{"lat":23.68791771,"lng":73.37660217},{"lat":23.74147797,"lng":73.42572021},{"lat":23.74196243,"lng":73.426651},{"lat":23.74204063,"lng":73.42706299},{"lat":23.74147797,"lng":73.42572021},{"lat":23.74172592,"lng":73.42608643},{"lat":23.7419014,"lng":73.42645264},{"lat":23.74196243,"lng":73.426651},{"lat":23.74204063,"lng":73.42706299},{"lat":23.74206543,"lng":73.42773438},{"lat":23.74203682,"lng":73.42796326},{"lat":23.74198532,"lng":73.42819214},{"lat":23.74111557,"lng":73.43011475},{"lat":23.74067307,"lng":73.4310379},{"lat":23.74047661,"lng":73.43149567},{"lat":23.74047661,"lng":73.43149567},{"lat":23.7404213,"lng":73.43172455},{"lat":23.74040222,"lng":73.4319458},{"lat":23.74040604,"lng":73.43215179},{"lat":23.68807602,"lng":73.37683868},{"lat":23.68820953,"lng":73.37711334},{"lat":23.68831253,"lng":73.37739563},{"lat":23.68842506,"lng":73.37791443},{"lat":23.68843269,"lng":73.37811279},{"lat":23.68850136,"lng":73.37839508},{"lat":23.68861198,"lng":73.37859344},{"lat":23.68872833,"lng":73.37875366},{"lat":23.7404747,"lng":73.43264008},{"lat":23.74053001,"lng":73.43276215},{"lat":23.74061584,"lng":73.4328537},{"lat":23.74071693,"lng":73.43292999},{"lat":23.74093246,"lng":73.43310547},{"lat":23.74093437,"lng":73.43310547},{"lat":23.68881416,"lng":73.37884521},{"lat":23.68890381,"lng":73.37895966},{"lat":23.68899155,"lng":73.37911987},{"lat":23.68909454,"lng":73.3792572},{"lat":23.68931389,"lng":73.37970734},{"lat":23.68934441,"lng":73.37981415},{"lat":23.68941689,"lng":73.37993622},{"lat":23.68944359,"lng":73.38013458},{"lat":23.74116325,"lng":73.43328857},{"lat":23.74129486,"lng":73.4333725},{"lat":23.74217796,"lng":73.433815},{"lat":23.68945312,"lng":73.38030243},{"lat":23.68942451,"lng":73.38047028},{"lat":23.68944359,"lng":73.38063049},{"lat":23.68943024,"lng":73.38078308},{"lat":23.68939018,"lng":73.38092804},{"lat":23.6893692,"lng":73.38106537},{"lat":23.68934059,"lng":73.3812027},{"lat":23.68927956,"lng":73.38140869},{"lat":23.74217796,"lng":73.433815},{"lat":23.7430439,"lng":73.43425751},{"lat":23.68897247,"lng":73.38247681},{"lat":23.68868637,"lng":73.3835144},{"lat":23.68855095,"lng":73.38401794},{"lat":23.68836403,"lng":73.38489532},{"lat":23.68838882,"lng":73.38507843},{"lat":23.68842888,"lng":73.38526917},{"lat":23.6884861,"lng":73.38544464},{"lat":23.68863869,"lng":73.38578033},{"lat":23.68874741,"lng":73.38592529},{"lat":23.68885994,"lng":73.38603973},{"lat":23.6891098,"lng":73.38620758},{"lat":23.68925858,"lng":73.3862381},{"lat":23.68941689,"lng":73.38626099},{"lat":23.69036102,"lng":73.38641357},{"lat":23.690588,"lng":73.38643646},{"lat":23.69151306,"lng":73.38653564},{"lat":23.74384308,"lng":73.43467712},{"lat":23.74384308,"lng":73.43467712},{"lat":23.69247246,"lng":73.38671875},{"lat":23.69293785,"lng":73.38677979},{"lat":23.69301605,"lng":73.38677216},{"lat":23.69343758,"lng":73.38677216},{"lat":23.69444275,"lng":73.38690948},{"lat":23.69530678,"lng":73.38705444},{"lat":23.69578552,"lng":73.38716888},{"lat":23.69628716,"lng":73.38735962},{"lat":23.74443245,"lng":73.4349823},{"lat":23.74455261,"lng":73.43508148},{"lat":23.74467468,"lng":73.43518829},{"lat":23.74482727,"lng":73.43528748},{"lat":23.69678307,"lng":73.38761902},{"lat":23.6980896,"lng":73.3884964},{"lat":23.69956017,"lng":73.38946533},{"lat":23.70085144,"lng":73.39022064},{"lat":23.70154762,"lng":73.39052582},{"lat":23.70227242,"lng":73.39074707},{"lat":23.70301628,"lng":73.3908844},{"lat":23.70376015,"lng":73.39093018},{"lat":23.74517822,"lng":73.43547058},{"lat":23.74517822,"lng":73.43547058},{"lat":23.74627686,"lng":73.43605042},{"lat":23.70512962,"lng":73.39086914},{"lat":23.70664215,"lng":73.39073944},{"lat":23.70817757,"lng":73.39058685},{"lat":23.70967484,"lng":73.39045715},{"lat":23.71029091,"lng":73.39046478},{"lat":23.7109108,"lng":73.39056396},{"lat":23.71248055,"lng":73.39098358},{"lat":23.71399498,"lng":73.39144897},{"lat":23.74757004,"lng":73.43674469},{"lat":23.71427155,"lng":73.39160156},{"lat":23.71453094,"lng":73.39178467},{"lat":23.71567345,"lng":73.39277649},{"lat":23.71662903,"lng":73.39360809},{"lat":23.71755409,"lng":73.39439392},{"lat":23.71852684,"lng":73.3952713},{"lat":23.71945953,"lng":73.39608002},{"lat":23.72032928,"lng":73.39683533},{"lat":23.74757004,"lng":73.43675232},{"lat":23.7490139,"lng":73.43751526},{"lat":23.72120094,"lng":73.39763641},{"lat":23.72187805,"lng":73.39823151},{"lat":23.72197151,"lng":73.39826965},{"lat":23.72205162,"lng":73.39827728},{"lat":23.72210884,"lng":73.39826965},{"lat":23.72212601,"lng":73.39826202},{"lat":23.72223091,"lng":73.39821625},{"lat":23.72230721,"lng":73.39813995},{"lat":23.75060654,"lng":73.43832397},{"lat":23.75060844,"lng":73.43832397},{"lat":23.7223587,"lng":73.3980484},{"lat":23.72232246,"lng":73.39807129},{"lat":23.72327423,"lng":73.39954376},{"lat":23.72395897,"lng":73.40013885},{"lat":23.72500229,"lng":73.40097809},{"lat":23.72584534,"lng":73.40168762},{"lat":23.72676659,"lng":73.40254974},{"lat":23.72746849,"lng":73.40312195},{"lat":23.75218582,"lng":73.43911743},{"lat":23.72817802,"lng":73.40377808},{"lat":23.72842216,"lng":73.40407562},{"lat":23.72868156,"lng":73.40444183},{"lat":23.72876358,"lng":73.40457916},{"lat":23.72889709,"lng":73.40481567},{"lat":23.72906685,"lng":73.40518188},{"lat":23.72920418,"lng":73.40555573},{"lat":23.72959137,"lng":73.40657043},{"lat":23.75349236,"lng":73.4397583},{"lat":23.75349426,"lng":73.4397583},{"lat":23.73003197,"lng":73.40763092},{"lat":23.73023796,"lng":73.40827942},{"lat":23.7303257,"lng":73.40871429},{"lat":23.73056984,"lng":73.40936279},{"lat":23.7310009,"lng":73.41044617},{"lat":23.7313633,"lng":73.41136932},{"lat":23.73171425,"lng":73.41223145},{"lat":23.73192406,"lng":73.41252899},{"lat":23.75437164,"lng":73.4401474},{"lat":23.73197746,"lng":73.41255951},{"lat":23.73232651,"lng":73.41336823},{"lat":23.73266029,"lng":73.41426086},{"lat":23.73283195,"lng":73.41464233},{"lat":23.73295021,"lng":73.41483307},{"lat":23.73323631,"lng":73.41521454},{"lat":23.73403931,"lng":73.41622925},{"lat":23.73497009,"lng":73.41738892},{"lat":23.75531387,"lng":73.44050598},{"lat":23.75531387,"lng":73.44051361},{"lat":23.73589897,"lng":73.4185791},{"lat":23.74184418,"lng":73.42860413},{"lat":23.7414608,"lng":73.42940521},{"lat":23.74111557,"lng":73.43011475},{"lat":23.75584602,"lng":73.44069672},{"lat":23.75596428,"lng":73.44071198},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.7562809,"lng":73.44078827},{"lat":23.75663948,"lng":73.44098663},{"lat":23.75675392,"lng":73.44104004},{"lat":23.75709534,"lng":73.44117737},{"lat":23.75709534,"lng":73.44117737},{"lat":23.75732231,"lng":73.4413147},{"lat":23.75786591,"lng":73.44166565},{"lat":23.75855064,"lng":73.44197083},{"lat":23.75855064,"lng":73.44197083},{"lat":23.7592926,"lng":73.44241333},{"lat":23.75946045,"lng":73.44250488},{"lat":23.76015282,"lng":73.44298553},{"lat":23.76015472,"lng":73.44298553},{"lat":23.76028061,"lng":73.44309998},{"lat":23.76033592,"lng":73.44313049},{"lat":23.76065826,"lng":73.44326782},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.7608242,"lng":73.44337463},{"lat":23.76147842,"lng":73.44379425},{"lat":23.76163292,"lng":73.44390106},{"lat":23.76163292,"lng":73.44390106},{"lat":23.76170921,"lng":73.44394684},{"lat":23.76192093,"lng":73.4440918},{"lat":23.76196098,"lng":73.44412231},{"lat":23.76206779,"lng":73.44415283},{"lat":23.76215172,"lng":73.4442215},{"lat":23.76215363,"lng":73.4442215},{"lat":23.76253128,"lng":73.44450378},{"lat":23.7626133,"lng":73.44458771},{"lat":23.7626133,"lng":73.44458771},{"lat":23.76315117,"lng":73.44509888},{"lat":23.76315117,"lng":73.44509888},{"lat":23.76351738,"lng":73.44541931},{"lat":23.76361465,"lng":73.44558716},{"lat":23.76369095,"lng":73.44577026},{"lat":23.76374817,"lng":73.44602966},{"lat":23.76376724,"lng":73.44629669},{"lat":23.76372719,"lng":73.44660187},{"lat":23.76365089,"lng":73.44685364},{"lat":23.76353455,"lng":73.44706726},{"lat":23.76336098,"lng":73.44723511},{"lat":23.7631588,"lng":73.44737244},{"lat":23.7631588,"lng":73.44737244},{"lat":23.76293755,"lng":73.44747925}.......
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#2f6682',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        icons: [{
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }]
      });
      flightPath.setMap(map);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4gtf.png
```

Comment: You should 1) Provide a working [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. 2) Explain clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like the coordinates in the path of the polyline are out of order: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4Lzfn3v9/).  Where did the coordinates for the polyline come from?  Why do you think they should be in the correct order?

Comment: If I sort the points in the line so that the next closest one is next in order, I get a reasonable polyline.  However, the best solution is to get the data in the correct order to start with.  Is there some reason the points are out of order?

Comment: @geocodezip The order is fine as its the same array which is used to plot markers. and i have verify the time of data i have received. If fine too. I think its the decimal values which is causing the problem. most of points are having upto 8 decimals but some having 6 decimals. What do you think??

Comment: Order doesn't matter for markers.  I think the points are out of order (but hard to say for sure, as the posted code isn't complete, but on the assumption that you just shortened the arrays, it would be helpful if you posted a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question**)